# displayTextView.setText("change in the code"); is wrong?

Tags: java, android, settext

A simple android Hello World:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.amaker.ch02.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView displayTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DisplayTextView);
        displayTextView.setText("change in the code");    <--Right if delete the line
    }
}
```

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/DisplayTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Run, and android will display: ***sorry, the application has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.***, but just as I point in the code `MainActivity.java`, if I delete the code `displayTextView.setText("change in the code");`, everything is OK.

What's wrong with the line of code?

Comment: does the textView show up without that line? Does it display the default text...? 

Also, try deleting the private modifier for the textView.

Comment: also, by convention, I believe variable names are supposed to be lowercase and then camelCase.

Comment: Oh, right, i have modified from "DisplayTextView" to "displayTextView", convention is also important. Thanks @Kgrover

Comment: But without "private", also "stopped unexpectedly"...@Kgrover

Comment: Your code is working fine... try to rebuild

Comment: Update this with your logcat, this will be easier to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems right. try to clean and build the project. also try to change textview id in xml as well as in your code.your `DisplayTextView` might coming null so creating this problem. debug the code and find the actual cause. or provide us logcat details.